# Azure Function Logs Location Locally

Tags: logging, azure-functions

Where can we find logs for Azure Functions (Java- for example) when we run it locally ?
It is not inside the target folder.
Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: By default it will log to the console when you run azure-functions-core-tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `"fileLoggingMode": "always"` to the logging configuration in your `host.json` file:

```json
{
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Trace"
      },
      "fileLoggingMode": "always"
    }
}
```

Functions Core Tools will then write log files to:

`%TMP%\LogFiles\Application\Functions`